# Why am I getting different output in these two timer function using time module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time

I have written a small function (timer1) to test the performance of code:

```
def timer1(func,*args):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(1000):
        func(*args)
    return time.perf_counter() - start
```

Another variation to this function (timer2) is as below:

```
def timer2(func,*args):
    for i in range(1000):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args)
    return time.perf_counter() - start
```

Printing the result:

```
timer1_o = timer1(pow,2,1000)
timer2_o = timer2(pow,2,1000)
print(f"Timer1 function output: {timer1_o}")
print(f"Timer2 function output: {timer2_o}")
print(f"Difference between timer1 and timer2: {abs(timer1_o - timer2_o)}")
```

Output:

```
Timer1 function output: 0.006264125000000009
Timer2 function output: 6.016999999969297e-06
Difference between timer1 and timer2: 0.00625810800000004
```

My main concern is why am I getting difference in execution time from both functions i.e. timer1 and timer2?

Comment: In your second loop you start the timer *in* the loop rather than *before*. That means that you time an almost nothing event.

Comment: `timer1()` returns the time taken by 1000 function calls.  `timer2()` returns the time taken by a single function call (the very last one), since the value of `start` gets overwritten 999 times.

Comment: timer1 measures 1000 pow(2,1000), and timer2 only measures 1.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: But when I checked the code on 'Thonny', I noticed that in second function, the value of 'start' variable was always increasing. If in second function it is overwriting the timer value 999 times, then why it is always increasing?

Comment: How could it do anything *but* increase?  It would only decrease if you were moving backwards through time.

Comment: perf_counter() returns the time that has elapsed since the start of the program, i.e. time since you hit the "run" button or F5. That's why this 
```return time.perf_counter() - start```
exist. But since the start variable is always overwrited in the timer2, the start var and the current time in the return statement only differs by 1 unit of time(time that the pow func takes).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code lies in `timer2`, as the comments have mentioned. In python, defining a variable in a loop **redefines the variable every time the loop iterates**, as shown below:

```
for i in range(1000):
    x = i
print(i)
```

**Output for above code:**

```
999
```

Here, variable `x` is being assigned to integer `i` every time the loop iterates, so only the last iteration sticks. This is your error in a nutshell: you're trying to get the start time of `timer2`, and find the time taken to run a function (`pow`) 1000 times. In `timer1`, you define start **only once**, when the function is called. in `timer2`, every time `pow` is run, `start` is redefined to the current time.

Here is an example (simplified) of what you're doing wrong.

```
from time import perf_counter, sleep

# Correct code
start = perf_counter()
for i in range(5):
    print(f"Value of start variable is {start}")    # Check the value of start variable
    sleep(1)        # Sleep for 5 * 1 seconds = 5 seconds
print(f"Total time taken is {perf_counter() - start}")
```

**Output:**

```
Value of start variable is 0.036466726
Value of start variable is 0.036466726
Value of start variable is 0.036466726
Value of start variable is 0.036466726
Value of start variable is 0.036466726
Total time taken is 5.00026942
```

You can clearly see **the value of `start` remains the same**

What you're doing in `timer2`:

```
from time import perf_counter, sleep

# WRONG code
for i in range(5):
    start = perf_counter()
    print(f"Value of start variable is {start}")    # Check the value of start variable
    sleep(1)        # Sleep for 5 * 1 seconds = 5 seconds
print(f"Total time taken is {perf_counter() - start}")
```

**Output:**

```
Value of start variable is 0.039062328
Value of start variable is 1.038552811
Value of start variable is 2.038591666
Value of start variable is 3.038642618
Value of start variable is 4.038716663
Total time taken is 1.0000285910000004
```

**`start` changes every iteration** with your `timer2` code.

Your `timer1` works just fine, stick to it.

Also, please read/watch about python loops, or play around with them till you know what they do. Avoid asking things on SO that you could instantly find answers to on google.

Comment: My main point of concern, however, was the working of perf_counter() in general. From your answer, my understanding about perf_counter is as below: In the simplified version of 'Wrong Code' when we iterate through next item in the sequence and passes through sleep(), the new start variable simply (in next iteration) adds up sleep time of 1 sec to previous stored value (0.039.. sec which was at the start of loop) and starts with a new stored value of (1+0.039=1.039..sec) in next loop. This cycle is repeated till the end.  So the last value of 'start' is 4.03..

Comment: But at the very end (during printing the message) why did perf_couner() took the value of 5 sec? Why not the last stored value of 'start' variable?

Comment: That is because of the order of my statements @AnuragGupta - the start variable is defined before the sleep function whereas the final `perf_counter` is defined after the sleep function. If you move the defining of `start` to after `sleep(1)`, you'd get 0 seconds approx.